# Getting Bad substitution error with a Shell Script on a mac?

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, sh, posix

I'm getting an error message "./query.sh: line 5: ${1,,}: bad substitution" whenever I run a shell script in a Mac OSX terminal

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )

if [ "$1" != "" ]; then
    letter1=$(echo ${1,,}|(cut -b1))new
    if [[ $letter1 == [a-zA-Z0-9] ]]; then
        if [ -f "$dir/data/$letter1" ]; then
            grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/data/$letter1"
        else
            letter2=$(echo ${1,,}|cut -b2)
            if [[ $letter2 == [a-zA-Z0-9] ]]; then
                if [ -f "$dir/data/$letter1/$letter2" ]; then
                    grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/data/$letter1/$letter2"
                else
                    letter3=$(echo ${1,,}|cut -b3)
                    if [[ $letter3 == [a-zA-Z0-9] ]]; then
                        if [ -f "$dir/data/$letter1/$letter2/$letter3" ]; then
                            grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/data/$letter1/$letter2/$letter3"
                        fi
                    else
                        if [ -f "$dir/data/$letter1/$letter2/symbols" ]; then
                            grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/data/$letter1/$letter2/symbols"
                        fi
                    fi
                fi
            else
                if [ -f "$dir/data/$letter1/symbols" ]; then
                    grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/data/$letter1/symbols"
                fi
            fi
        fi
    else
        if [ -f "$dir/data/symbols" ]; then
            grep -ai "^$1" "$dir/data/symbols"
        fi
    fi
else
    echo "[*] Example: ./query name@domain.com"
fi
```

The scripts function is to search throuhg a huge number of data files so could anybody help me pinpoint the source of the problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `,,` operator was introduced in `bash` 4.0, but `/bin/bash` on macOS is still version 3.2. You can install a newer version of `bash` and change your shebang accordingly, or you can use `letter1=$(echo "$1" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | cut -b1)` instead.

(You can, however, use `${letter:0:1}`, `${letter:1:1}`, etc, in place of a call to `cut` to get a single letter from the string.)

My advice is to treat `/bin/bash` on macOS as nothing more than a POSIX-compatible shell. Use `#!/bin/sh` if you want a portable script, or use `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` (or whatever is appropriate, after installing a new version of `bash`) if you want to take advantage of `bash` extensions at the expense of portability.

Comment: Shouldn't the POSIX character classes just have a single square bracket? The arguments to `tr` are character classes, not regular expressions. (Replacing `[` with `[` is harmless as such, of course.)

Comment: Thanks, helped fix my problem

Comment: @tripleee I think there are some tr versions around that need the extra set of brackets. I read "In the System V version of `tr`, square brackets must surround any range of characters" in "Unix Power Tools" - but I agree that probably most `tr`s "in the wild" support the single bracket syntax.

Comment: Oh, probably; `tr` is the only program I'm aware of that doesn't require a character class to be in a bracket expression.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a subshell to produce the value anyway, you might as well change the call to something which is portable back to earlier versions of Bash.

Running `cut -b1` in a subshell (in parentheses) is useless and doing it after the conversion means you convert a potentially long string and then discard everything except the first character.

```
letter1=$(echo "${1:0:1}" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')new
```

Notice also the double quotes around the argument to `echo`.

Do you really want the suffix `new` to be attached to the value?  The first condition in the `if` can never match in that case.

You should probably also refactor the code to avoid the deep ["arrow antipattern"](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrowAntiPattern) and only perform the `grep` once you have a value for the file name you want to search.

Comment: arrow anti-pattern. nice term for it!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, the builtin bash on Mac is very old and must be upgraded to use some operators, e.g. the caret operator. If you use homebrew, run `brew install bash` and follow the instructions in [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/292760).